# Cannot get props from useStyles material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I'm trying to pass my current index in useStyles hook to display my component depending of this index like this :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  console.log(theme);
  return {
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1,
      display: theme.props.currentIndex !== 0 ? 'none' : void 0
    }
  };
});
```

I saw that we can pass props to useStyle hook, so I passed my current value to use it in makeStyles :

```
const AcademicDegresPanel = props => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);
  console.log(props.currentIndex)
  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      Degrés academique
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

But when i log my theme, it has not the currentIndex in props key :

```
palette: {common: {…}, type: "light", primary: {…}, secondary: {…}, error: {…}, …}
props:
__proto__: Object
```

How can I use my current index in makeStyles instead of using inline style ?

Comment: to many code for this, I juste needed to display tab depending on index, I received my answer, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
const useStyles = props => makeStyles(theme => ({/* ... */ })();

or 

const useStyles = props => {
// style construction
return makeStyles(style)();
};
```

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped. Please accept the answer so other visitors can spot it fast